# regex using preg-match on de limited based string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got a string that goes like

```
Text58||INPUT 6~~Text67||INPUT 7~~Text68||INPUT 8~~CR_Exp_Date||INPUT 9~~Text60||INPUT 10~~Text63||INPUT 14~~Combo_Box65||Ship~~Text66||INPUT 15~~First_Name||INPUT 18~~Middle_Name||INPUT 19~~Last_Name||INPUT 20~~Suffix||INPUT 21~~Country||INPUT 22~~Mailing_Address||INPUT 23~~City||INPUT 24~~State||INPUT 25~~Zip_Code||INPUT 26~~
```

trying to extract `First_Name||INPUT 18`

tried doing `(?=First_Name[||]).*?(?<=[~~][$])`

didnt come up with anything else ...any ones what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Looks like you need to reread the description of `[...]` in regular expressions. `[||]` is the same as `[|]`, they both match a single `|` character.

Comment: And if you want to match `First_Name`, why are you putting it in a lookbehind instead of the text of the RE?

Comment: @Barmar well was trying copy from certian exmaples that had similar problems and solutions

Comment: What is the `[$]` for? There's no `$` in your input string.

Comment: @Barmar removed it still does not show me anything... (?=First_Name[|])*?(?<=[~])

Comment: Why do you expect that to work? It only matches one `|` but your string has two of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
First_Name\|\|.*?(?=~~)
```

- `First_Name` should not be in a lookahead, you want to include it in the match.
- To match a pair of `|`, you should include them in the regexp, with `\` to escape them.
- `~~` should be in a positive lookahead, not lookbehind. And they don't need to be in brackets.

If you don't want to include `First_Name||` in the match (why did you say you did in the question?), you can use a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=First_Name\|\|).*?(?=~~)
```

It seems like you got lookbehind and lookahead backwards in your attempt.

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37eg3)

Comment: okay it works but suppose i just want the INPUT 18 instead of "First_Name||INPUT 18" - i know i could a explode or sub string but just curious if i can avoid the step

Comment: still gives me "First_Name||INPUT 18"